# github files not the same as latest commit?

Tags: github

I am having trouble understanding/ updating one of my git repos. There is one branch, master. I created the repo on github. Cloned and made edits in Windows, commited, pushed. Cloned in Mac, made edits, committed, and pushed. A few days later made commits from Windows again. Now Github shows my latest commit different code than the files do.  Shouldn't github files be synced to the latest commit?

On my Windows machine the repo matches the commit changes shown in the latest commit. (The commit hash link in upper right of github.)
This is different from the repo and on my Mac, which matches the Raw file.

1. Why does the commit hash show a file with changes, while clicking the file link show the file before the changes? (seems to be root of problem)
2. How can the files be different than the most current commit?

The repo in question:

The file:

https://github.com/dval/HWiNFO64-Crunch/blob/master/HWiNFO64%20parsing.R

The hash:

https://github.com/dval/HWiNFO64-Crunch/commit/57c44c441ee0d2b39fa5248eaf44b10a3658a023

Comment: Both links lead to a 404, could the repo maybe be private?

Comment: Sorry, should be public now.

Comment: The links you posted link to different files, one to the commit changing the file ``HWiNFO64 parsing threaded.R``, and one to the file ``HWiNFO64 parsing.R``.

Comment: Well, at least it was an easy fix.... It's probably time I took a break. Thanks.